# What does -expand really mean with WMI (Powershell Select-Object)

Tags: wmi, powershell-4.0

This page on [Select-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) says only that -ExpandProperty "Specifies a property to select, and indicates that an attempt should be made to expand that property."  Do you remember the old rule that a definition should not include the word being defined, i.e. what is really being expanded?

Here's my proof of concept code:

```
get-wmiobject -class CIM_VideoController
$VideoController = get-wmiobject -class CIM_VideoController
$VideoProcessorEx = $VideoController | select-object -expand   VideoProcessor
$VideoProcessor   = $VideoController | select-object -property VideoProcessor
Write-Host "VideoProcessorEx =$VideoProcessorEx"
Write-Host "VideoProcessor=$VideoProcessor"
```

The first line of code shows the processor to be this:

```
VideoProcessor               : Quadro 1000M
```

The two Write-Host statements show this:

```
VideoProcessorEx =Intel(R) HD Graphics Family Quadro 1000M
VideoProcessor=
```

So part of my question is this.  Is the VideoProcessor really "Quadro 1000M' or "Intel(R) HD Graphics Family Quadro 1000M", or both are correct, one is the short name and one is the long (or expanded) name?  How do I retrieve the short name into a variable?

As per response from "halfknot", I added this:

```
Write-Host "************* Get-Member of `$VideoProcessor **********************" 
$VideoProcessor   | get-member

Write-Host "VideoProcessor via obj.property = $($VideoProcessor.VideoProcessor)"
```

and got this result:

```
************* Get-Member of $VideoProcessor **********************
TypeName   : Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject
Name       : Equals
MemberType : Method
Definition : bool Equals(System.Object obj)

TypeName   : Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject
Name       : GetHashCode
MemberType : Method
Definition : int GetHashCode()

TypeName   : Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject
Name       : GetType
MemberType : Method
Definition : type GetType()

TypeName   : Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject
Name       : ToString
MemberType : Method
Definition : string ToString()

TypeName   : Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject
Name       : VideoProcessor
MemberType : NoteProperty
Definition : System.String VideoProcessor=Intel(R) HD Graphics Family

VideoProcessor via obj.property = Intel(R) HD Graphics Family  Quadro 1000M
```

I'm still unclear why it doesn't just dispaly "Quadro 1000M" as per the original output of the WMI class.

Answer (score 1):

When you expand a property (-expandproperty) and assign it to a variable you are essentially saying give me the value of that property as a string. Opposed to to assigning the object itself to the variable. My guess is that VideoProcessor is a object that has multiple properties.

If you do a gm on each item i'm sure you'll get a better idea of what your dealing with

> $VideoProcessorEx | get-member
>
> $VideoProcessor | get-member

Comment: Updated my question with your idea... still unclear.  It is clearly returning an object, not a string.  Looks like maybe -expandproperty is calling a .ToString() for that object?

Comment: Run this.. "VideoController.VideoProcessor | gm" and note the properties/noteproperties

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have two `VideoController` entities, with one being `Intel HD Graphics`, and the other being `Quadro 1000M`. If you run plain `$VideoController.VideoProcessor` you will get two strings instead of one. So here's the confusion, you have missed the first entity returned by `get-wmiobject -class CIM_VideoController` as it has scrolled way too upwards to be visible, and thus you are interpreting two different values as a single value.